# Need help getting my connect four game to register four are in a row

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to get my connect four game register four of the same color circles are in a row. This is the last step i need in this game before its complete so any help would be greatly appreciated. The game is using java script code.

This is a link to my game.
https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/connect-four/4873312535379968

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, If you could add in some relevant code rather than just a link to a website, then this question will get more attention. Also include what you have tried and what hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that gets run every time you place a circle down. This function can do something simple like recursively check [up, down, left, right, diagonal up-right, diagonal up-left, diagonal down-right, diagonal-left] if there are 4 in a row, and if there are end the game.

Rough code could look something like this:

```
    var gameOver = function(position, color) {
        var directions = ['up', 'down', 'left', 'right', 'up-left', 'up-right', 'down-left', 'down-right'];
        for(var i = 0; i < directions.length; i++) {
            if (gameOverHelper(position, color, 0, directions[i])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    var gameOverHelper = function(position, color, currLength, direction) {
        if (currLength === 4) {
            return true;
        }
        switch(direction) {
            case 'up':
                //check and recursively call if needed
            .
            .
            .
        }
    }
```